# Importing SQL file with foreign key constraints

Tags: sql, sqlite, import, foreign-keys

I created a SQL file that has foreign key constraints in several tables.

When I enter the following line into the terminal:

```
sqlite3 language_application.db < language_application.sql
```

I get the following errors:

```
Error: near line 13: near "native_lang": syntax error
Error: near line 24: near "user_id_no": syntax error
Error: near line 34: near "request_id": syntax error
```

Only the tables that have the foreign key constraints seem to be giving me a problem.

I know that Sqlite3 has foreign key support disabled by default, but I don't know how to enable them and import the sql file into the database at the same time. I tried doing

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;
```

before importing the data, but then I don't know how to import the data while sqlite3 is running, other than that first line I wrote in the beginning of this question.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: What are the first fourteen lines of that SQL file?

Comment: `PRAGMA foreign_keys` does not affect syntax parsing rules, just whether the foreign keys are enforced. So the syntax errors won't get fixed with that `PRAGMA`. Please post the problematic parts of the SQL.

Comment: Yeah, it was a syntax error on my part, which I've since fixed. I didn't enclose my foreign key constraints with parentheses. But the .read solution was still helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first get the sqlite running, then among the instructions started with a period, there is a .read FILENAME which you can use to import sql statements written in a separate text file. The whole list of instructions could be accessed by typing .help in the sqlite3 console.